# Can Haar measure fail to be bi-invariant without conjugation shrinking a set?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

Let $\: \langle \hspace{-0.02 in}G,\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot,\hspace{-0.04 in}\mathcal{T}\hspace{.02 in}\rangle \:$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, let $\mu$ be a [left Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure)

on $\: \langle \hspace{-0.02 in}G,\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot,\hspace{-0.04 in}\mathcal{T}\hspace{.02 in}\rangle \:$, $\:$ and suppose that $\mu$ is *not* right-invariant. $\;\;\;\;$ Does it follow that there is a

Borel subset $B$ of $G$ and an element $g$ of $G$ such that $\:\operatorname{closure}(B)\:$ is compact and for $C$ defined by

$C \;\;\;\; = \;\;\;\; \{ \; h\in G \:\: : \:\: g^{\hspace{-0.02 in}-1} hg \: \in \: B \; \} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$, $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $\: C\subset B \;\;$ and $\;\; \operatorname{interior}(B\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.04 in}C\hspace{.02 in}) \neq \{\hspace{.02 in}\} \;\;\;$?

(In other words, is there ever a less trivial reason why the Haar measures are not bi-invariant?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A compact set containing the identity.

A good example to see is $G=\{\pmatrix{* & * \cr 0 & 1}\}$ with real entries, for example (or $p$-adic). The diagonal subgroup $M$ normalizes the subgroup $N=\{\pmatrix{1&*\cr 0&1}\}$, and while both $N$ and $M$ individually are unimodular, the normalization action of $M$ on $N$ has the effect of shrinking or expanding sets... especially in $N$ near the identity.

Comment: B can be the elements whose coordinates are all in the interval [0,1] and g can be the element whose upper row is $\langle 1/2,0\rangle$. $\;$